# Terminology surrounding superconductors and the Meissner-Ochsenfeld effect

Tags: condensed-matter, terminology, superconductivity

As stated in (Annett, 2004;pg 55) not all materials whose resistances vanishes exhibit the Meissner-Ochsenfeld effect (MOE). Which of these is therefore the defining property of a superconductor (if either)? And...

- If it is the vanishing resistance - is there a specific name given to superconductors that do not show the MOE?
- If it is  the MOE - is there a specific name given to the materials that have vanishing resistance but do not exhibit the MOE.

Comment: If Annett says that *not all materials whose resistance vanishes exhibit the Meißner-Ochsenfeld effect* (MOE), then it's clear that MOE is the phenomenology of a superconductor ... A perfect conductor has no resistance, but it's not a superconductor. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superconductivity and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_conductor if you want to learn some basics.